# MySQL 5.7 and 8 on a same ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I tried to ran MySQL 5.7 and 8 on same ubuntu server. 5.7 already installed by using apt installation. now what I need to run MySQL 8 without installation as Linux Using Generic Binaries.
Any one had an experience like some sort of scenario. And there are have so many errors follows.

mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2022-07-18T13:53:28.760521Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /home/mysql8/mysql8base/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) starting as process 23505
2022-07-18T13:53:28.764470Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-07-18T13:53:28.764766Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /home/mysql8/mysql8base/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Comment: not clear what you mean by "without installation".  you should be able to do this with enough fiddling, but why?  just use a different server, or a vm or container in the existing server

Comment: Without installation means that Installing MySQL on Unix/Linux Using Generic Binaries. this is on cloud environment cant not get another server. container mean docker  ?

Comment: docker uses containers, yes

Comment: containers mean OCI containers, which docker, podman, singularity and other runtimes can execute in an OCI Runtime Specification manner.